# How to get list of objects accessible to a project?

Tags: delphi, otapi

I'm trying to figure out how to access a list of objects available in the Delphi IDE (ie., from different namespaces) from within a component editor. (Also from the same editor form running independently.) LiveBindings do it, and there's a video where they say you have to have a unit listed in a uses clause in order for the LiveBinding editor to see the classes defined inside that unit. But it does not have to be a form.

I can access forms through the `Application.components` array, but that only gives me access to the `TForm` objects. Any classes defined in the same units with the form aren't visible, nor are classes defined in any units that are *not* forms.

Someone suggested the answer lies buried somewhere in the Open Tools API.

I thought there might be someone here who could shed a bit more light on the subject.

BTW, I'm using DXE5, but anything from version XE and up is probably the same.

NOTE: I did find a property somewhere that lists every single class and record defined in the entire freaking ecosystem. There are hundreds of them! That's not much help. Still looking.

Comment: Are you referring to the objects that are part of the Delphi application being edited by the IDE or the objects in the IDE itself?

Comment: User-defined objects. LiveBindings let you bind to fields and properties in both objects and forms in your app. I know how to find the forms; I'm trying to figure out how to find the objects. (The IDE apparently pre-compiles everything and keeps the info around internally somewhere, so it's possible to get access to it at design-time from within the IDE.)